# Tool for temporary data storage in Django

Tags: django, database, storage

In my PostgreSQL powered Django application, I collect data that are intended to be sent to a third party application through an API that is rate-limited.

The procedure is the following:

- Collect data through a web form
- Temporarily save the data in a "waiting room" for 24 -48 hours
- Use an internal mechanism to collect the data and send them to a third party
- Delete the data that were successfully sent

The question is how can I build this "waiting room"? What tool is best suited for this use?

Daniel Roseman has written an article on [Temporary Models in Django](https://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/04/13/temporary-models-django/), but this might not be a good solution for the case.

Comment: Why do you think you need anything else than a plain model ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers This is a good suggestion, what puzzles me is that I will delete the model's contents all the time and sometimes I will delete the same entry more than once! It feels better if I store long lasting data in the database but I cannot justify it, hence the question.

Comment: Well if you already have redis set up and your datasets are not too huge  you could use it (but beware you'll need to set it up for persistance), but as far as I'm concerned I wouldn't bother setting up an additional service (and eventually node) just for this.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Actually a bell just rang, I am already using [django disk cache](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/). It seems to be a good solution for a persistent local cache without the burden of the extra service.

Comment: looks like you found a good candidate indeed. Just beware of not having the cache clearing up before you expect

Comment: oh and yes while we're at it... pgsql is not only a relational database, it's also a key value and a json db.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers This is great news about pgsql! Could you please post an example in an answer to accept?

Comment: I'm afraid not - I barely used those features and that was some time ago already - but those are documented features (look for "htsore" and "json"). Note that those are actually datatypes for table columns so you'll still need a table, but without the burden of a fully fledged relational model. I just thought this was worth mentionning, not sure you will find it a better solution than django-disk-cache or redis but at least you won't have to worry about the cache wiping out your data before you sent them.

Comment: An introduction: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/07/14/choosing-nosql-hstore-json-jsonb/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you very much, very useful link. It really makes sense to use such a field in an already existing model, it is what I was looking for! [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.HStoreField) is up-to-date with those fields. Really great.

Comment: Glad I could help. I reposted this as an answer in case you want to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with using a cache for "temporary" storage is that you may end up with you data wipped out the cache before you used them.

Now since you're using Postgres, it's also a key value (hstore) and a json/jsonb db. You can read more about those types here: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/07/14/choosing-nosql-hstore-json-jsonb/

This still require using a table for your storage (those are fields types), but at least you avoid the burden of a fully fledged relational model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django cache for that. For example one powered by Redis: http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/